# For the polynomial $P = x^2 + 3x + 1$ $\in Z [x]$, determine the zeros of P modulo 11/121

Tags: polynomials

For the polynomial $P = x^2 + 3x + 1$ $\in Z [x]$, determine the zeros of $P$ modulo $11$, i.e. in $Z/11Z$, as well as at least one zero modulo $11^2 = 121$, i.e. in $Z/121Z$.

I see, there is a polynomial degree 2, so i know the polynomial has a maximum of two zeros.

Trying P modulo 11, for P(0-6) we get zeros in $P(2) = 2^2+3*2+1 = 11 mod 11 = 0$ and $P(6) = 55 mod 11 = 0$ , with two zeros, i can stop now.

But how i have to solve the task for $Z/121Z$ is there a faster way without trying it for every number from P(0-120)?

Comment: Well, you know that any solution would have to be $2$ or $6\pmod {11}$, which drastically shortens your search.

Comment: More specifically, you can look for a solution of the form $2+11k$, say.

Comment: @lulu hm.. ty!^^ i got it for k=3 with 2+11*3= 35 with x=35

Comment: Perfect.  Now do the same for $6+11k$.

Comment: Now ive got it for 7 and now ive got one more question with these informations. Is it clear  that each, 2+11k and 6+11k has one zero, or is it possible that 2+11k has two zeros or 6+11k has two zeros?

Comment: If it had more solutions, you'd have found them.  Your calculation ought to have confirmed that , in each case, the "lifted" solution is unique.

Comment: Should stress:  the uniqueness is not always true.  Take $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ for instance.  Try to lift the solution $x\equiv 1 \pmod 2$  up to $\pmod 8$.  You should get $4$ solutions.